# How to redirect to not found page if slug doesn't exist using React Router Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Let's say I have these routes:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug" component={Home} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/register" component={Signup} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/event" component={Event} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/contact" component={Contact} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/login" component={Login} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/show-details" component={ShowList} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/*" component={NotFound} />
  <Route path="*" exact={true} component={NotFound} />
  <Redirect to="/not-found" />

  {/* <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> */}
</Switch>
```

We have certain slugs from an API, in this form:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "_flix",
    slug: "_flix",
    status: true,
    viewTime: null,
    langue: null,
    createdAt: "2021-06-24",
    updatedAt: null,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: "test_flix",
    slug: "test_flix",
    status: true,
    viewTime: null,
    langue: null,
    createdAt: "2021-06-24",
    updatedAt: null,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    title: "flix_2",
    slug: "flix_2",
    status: true,
    viewTime: null,
    langue: null,
    createdAt: "2021-06-24",
    updatedAt: null,
  },
]
```

When I make an invalid slug, I want to redirect to the `NotFound` page:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getSlug(slug)
    .then((res) => {
      const { id } = res.data;
      document.title = res.data.title;
      getSetting(id).then((result) => {
        setStyle(result.data);
        getLangue(id).then((res) => {
          setlang(res.data.langue);
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => (window.location.href = "/not-found"));
}, [slug]);
```

I used the above code (see the `.catch`), but when I make an invalid slug, it redirects not found page and refreshes the page. I need to redirect without refreshing. Any solution?

Comment: As the answer below shows, we don't use `window` or `document` directly in React.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href` refreshes the page. Since you seem to be using React Router Dom `v5`, you should be using [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) to make redirections. Here is an  overview of how you would use it (notice the comments):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory(); // you call it at the top level of the component

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home"); // use it wherever you want
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Not related to `useHistory` or the redirection, but you could optimize slightly your routes setup:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug" component={Home} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/register" component={Signup} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/event" component={Event} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/contact" component={Contact} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/login" component={Login} />
  <Route exact path="/myflix/:slug/show-details" component={ShowList} />
  <Route exact path="/not-found" component={NotFound} />
  <Redirect to="/not-found" />
</Switch>
```

For React Router Dom `v6`, use [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate) is to be used instead of [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks).

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Using `window.location.href = "/not-found"` mutates the current location and reloads the page, i.e. it will remount the entire React app. Use an imperative redirect to the `"/not-found"` route.

## Solution

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const history = useHistory();

...

useEffect(() => {
  getSlug(slug)
    .then((res) => {
      const { id, title } = res.data;
      document.title = title;
      getSetting(id)
        .then((result) => {
          setStyle(result.data);
        });
      getLangue(id)
        .then((res) => {
          setLang(res.data.langue);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      history.replace("/not-found"); // REPLACE = redirect
    });
}, [slug]);
```

Render a `Route` on `path="/not-found"` that can be redirected to.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/myflix/:slug/register" component={Signup} />
  <Route path="/myflix/:slug/event" component={Event} />
  <Route path="/myflix/:slug/contact" component={Contact} />
  <Route path="/myflix/:slug/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/myflix/:slug/show-details" component={ShowList} />
  <Redirect from="/myflix/:slug/*" to="/not-found" /> // <-- redirect unhandled paths
  <Route path="/myflix/:slug" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFound} /> // <-- render NotFound component route
  <Redirect to="/not-found" />
</Switch>
```